# replace a white pixel with a black pixel in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-2.x

I've converted an image, `myImage`, to grayscale and loaded it into a numpy array.

For reference, `myImage.shape` returns `(184L, 184L)`

In cases where `myImage` is completely white. That is, all `255` pixel values. How do I replace a white pixel with a black pixel `0`?

It could be 1 or 2 or 10 black pixel replacements. I just need the number of black pixels to not be null.

Comment: I am absolutely sure. You don't want to insert, you want to change a value by index.

Comment: `if np.all(myImage==255): myImage[0]=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment: *i'd like to take the first white pixel (255) and change it to a black pixel (0)*, You can use:

```
myImage[0,0] = 0
```

Minimal Example:

```
myImage = np.ones((5,5))*255
>>> myImage
array([[255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255.]])

myImage[0,0] = 0

>>> myImage
array([[  0., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something more general

```
import numpy as np
image = np.ones((5,5))*255
old_val = 255
new_val = 0
image[image==old_val]=new_val
```

Comment: Wouldn't this replace *all* the pixels?

Comment: All the pixels with value equal to 255